# How can I check if a particular value exists in a particular column in google app engine datastore?(python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Suppose I have a table with the Column A and B.

I want to find out whether a particular field exists in Column A. I also want to know how many of them are there

Comment: You should try to move away from the idea of a "table" when thinking about the GAE data store. If you think about it like about a regular RDB, the differences between the systems are going to bite you pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a Model that looks like this:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

You can query the existence of a particular value and/or the total number of entities which have that value in a property, you can query like so:

```
def jack_chan_in_employee():
    query = Employee.all()
    count = query.filter('name =', 'Jacky Chan').count()
    return count
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to check from another .py file?

Comment: import the module that contains the models from that other file?